# Hierachical Random Mixed effect sizes

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, glmm

When using a mixed effect model the rule of thumb seems to be that you need at least 5 levels to use a random factor . Is this still True when you have a hieachical model.
i.e 
A - 4 level factor
B - 3 level factor
C - 6 level factor

with a formula of

y~1+(1|A/B/C)

Will the first 2 levels just cause issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nested design, it is the combinations of the levels of the factors that is important.

```
y ~ 1 + (1|A/B/C)
```

expands to

```
y ~ 1 + (1|A) + (1|A:B) + (1|A:B:C)
```

So, you need to apply the rule of thumb to the levels of `A`, the levels of the interaction `A:B` and the levels of the interaction `A:B:C`. In the example you give, `A` has 4 levels, `A:B` has 12 levels and `A:B:C` has 72 levels.

It is debatable whether 4 levels is sufficient, and at the end of the day, pragmatism is probably the best approach:

1. Does the data support that random structure? That is, does the model converge and is it non-singular ?
2. Are the random effects plausibly normally distributed ?
3. Does the model fit adequately ?

Comment: Thanks, I think the expansion was what I was missing. I'll investigate the other points.